# Generics: How to get values of a Map without casting

Tags: java, generics, collections, casting, hashmap

I have an abstract class named `BaseCode` and 2 concrete classes named `Location` and `Department`:

```
public abstract class BaseCode {
   private Integer id;
   ...
   public Integer getId() { return id; }
   public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
   ...
}

public class Location extends BaseCode {
   ...
}

public class Department extends BaseCode {
   ...
}
```

I have an abstract class named `BaseCodeCache` and 2 concrete classes named `LocationCache` and `DepartmentCache`. `LocationCache` and `DepartmentCache` will be using `Singleton`.

```
public abstract class BaseCodeCache {
   ...
}

public class LocationCache extends BaseCodeCache {
   ...
}

public class DepartmentCache extends BaseCodeCache {
   ...
}
```

---

1. In `BaseCodeCache`, I want to have a `java.util.Map` whose value can
   be any type of `BaseCode` i.e. `Location` objects or `Department`
   objects.
   In `LocationCache`, I want the `java.util.Map` to store `Location` objects. 
   In `DepartmentCache`, I want the `java.util.Map` to store `Department` objects.

To accomplish this, I put this code in `BaseCodeCache`:

```
private Map<Integer, BaseCode> idMap = new HashMap<Integer, BaseCode>();
```

---

2. I want to have a method to store a value in the
   `java.util.Map`.

To accomplish this, I put this code in `BaseCodeCache`:

```
public void add(BaseCode baseCode) {
   if (baseCode != null) {
      idMap.put(baseCode.getId(), baseCode);
   }
}
```

This is how I would use it for `Location`:

```
Location location = new Location(); ...
LocationCache.getInstance().add(location);
```

This is how I would use it for `Department`:

```
Department department = new Department(); ...
DepartmentCache.getInstance().add(department);
```

---

3. I want to have a method to get all values in the `java.util.Map` as
   a `java.util.List`. 
   In `LocationCache` this method should return `List<Location>`. 
   In `DepartmentCache` this method should return `List<Department>`.

**Thats where I am stuck.** I want to create this method in `BaseCodeCache` but when this method is called via `LocationCache` then it returns `List<Location>` and when this same method is called via `DepartmentCache` then it returns `List<Department>`. **Is it possible?**

I put this code in `BaseCodeCache`:

```
public List<BaseCode> getList() {
   return new ArrayList<BaseCode>(idMap.values());
}
```

But the above code returns `List<BaseCode>`. When I would call it this way:

```
List<Location> allLocations = LocationCache.getInstance().getList();
```

Then java will not let it compile and give this error message:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<BaseCode>` to `List<Location>`

I can get it fixed by getting `List<BaseCode>` and then converting it to `List<Location>` by looping but thats does not look right.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement using generics as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseCodeCache<T extends BaseCode> {
    private Map<Integer, T> idMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(T baseCode) {
        if (baseCode != null) {
            idMap.put(baseCode.getId(), baseCode);
        }
    }

    public List<T> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<>(idMap.values());
    }
}

public class LocationCache extends BaseCodeCache<Location> {}

public class DepartmentCache extends BaseCodeCache<Department> {}
```

---

This will then enable you to do the following *without* any compilation errors:

```
LocationCache locationCache = new LocationCache();
locationCache.add(new Location());

List<Location> locations = locationCache.getList();
```

Even better, you *will* get compilation errors if you try to add or retrieve the wrong type of objects:

```
locationCache.add(new Department()); // won't compile
List<Department> departments = locationCache.getList(); // won't compile
```

Comment: Thanks man. This is awesome. One question. Is there a name to the type of generics you are using? If yes please mention. TIA

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "type of generics". The example above is really just generics 101, the kind of first example you would find in a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. I find out that you are using a **bounded type parameter** T.

Comment: Stat rosa pristina nomine, nomina nuda tenemus